# Php equivalent to Javascript's Array.from()

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to convert a piece of javascript over to php to work how I need it to, however I cannot find an equivalent to this method without writing far more code than needed.

```
const digits = Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => [randomNumber(4), randomNumber(4)]).concat(
        Array(20).fill([1,1]));

function randomNumber(limit) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit) + 1;
}
```

Comment: What does `randomNumber()` do? I mean what does it **exactly** do. I cannot run your code now.

Comment: just generates a random number; return Math.floor(Math.random()*limit)+1;

Comment: Instead of this very narrow API specific focus, understand what this code is supposed to *do*, and implement PHP code that’ll lead to the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ok, you can first fill the array with `[1,1]` already of size `70` using [array_fill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php).
- Now, you can just walk over the array using [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and check if `$key` is less than `50`. If yes, you generate the random numbers, else you can leave it as is.

  ```
  $arr = array_fill(0,70,[1,1]);
  array_walk($arr,function(&$value,$key){
      if($key < 50) list($value[0],$value[1]) = [rand(0,4),rand(0,4)];
  });
  ```

Comment: Other than the fact that OP's `randomNumber()` returns between 1 & 4 and yours is 0 & 4 this looks good. Also `69` should be `70`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it using [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php). We pass it an array of all the numbers from 1 to 70 (generated using [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)), using the value to determine whether to add a random 2 element array or the fixed array to our output array:

```
$arr = array_reduce(range(1, 70), function ($c, $v) { 
    $c[] = $v <= 50 ? [rand(1, 4), rand(1,4)] : [1,1];
    return $c;
}, []);
```